# FragmentStatePagerAdapter is unable to keep state

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am currently working on a quiz app for a project in my Android Development course and I am having an issue while using Fragments, specifically the FragmentStatePagerAdapter.

The app is supposed to give you six questions and you should be able to swipe left and right to navigate between the questions. This functionality works. It looks like this:

[image]

These questions and answers are created dynamically from a db using Android Room. I generate 6 unique questions and each question adds a Fragment to the FragmentStatePagerAdapter. The problem comes when you actually swipe through the questions. Once you reach question 3, and you scroll back to question 1, then question 1 looks like this:

[image]

I realize that the Fragment gets destroyed and then restored. However, using Log.d I found out that the onCreate still calls exactly the same and even retrieves all of the answers again. The problem is that it is not assigning it to the radio buttons and I do not know why. The onCreate for the fragment looks like this:

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                         @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup)inflater.inflate(R.layout.page_1, container, false);

    states = rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView5);
    radioGroup = rootView.findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
    questionCount = rootView.findViewById(R.id.questionCount);

    answerRadios.add(rootView.findViewById(R.id.radioButton));
    answerRadios.add(rootView.findViewById(R.id.radioButton2));
    answerRadios.add(rootView.findViewById(R.id.radioButton3));

    questionCount.setText("Question " + order + "/6");

    // Gets the question in this particular order
    LiveDataUtil.observeOnce(db.questions().getQuestion(qId, order), (question) -> {
        states.setText("What is the capital of " + question.state + "?");

        // Get the answers for the question
        LiveDataUtil.observeOnce(db.answers().getAnswers(question.id), (answers) -> {
            for (int i = 0, len = answers.size(); i < len; i++) {
                RadioButton radio = answerRadios.get(i);
                QuizAnswer answer = answers.get(i);

                radio.setText(answer.answerText);
            }
        });

         radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener
          ...more code
    });

    return rootView;
}
```

Fragment Template (page_1.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:text="Capital Quiz!"
        android:textSize="36sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/questionCount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:text="Question 1/6" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="QUESTION"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:text="Answer 1" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:text="Answer 2" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Answer 3" />
    </RadioGroup>
</LinearLayout>
```

Just for reference, the LiveDataUtil looks like this:

```
public class LiveDataUtil {
    public static <T> void observeOnce(LiveData<T> liveData, Observer<T> observer) {
        liveData.observeForever(o -> {
            liveData.removeObserver(observer);
            observer.onChanged(o);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried simply observing livedata normally instead of using `observeOnce` method?

Comment: Yes, the problem persists

Comment: @Pawel There seems to be an issue with using a List of RadioButton's. Using `rootView.findViewById(R.id.radioButton)` directly works but `answerRadios.get(0);` does not work.

Comment: If that's the case it could mean your fragment is not destroyed entirely, only it's view hierarchy is. You can try adding `answerRadios.clear()` before populating it, or logging `onDestroy` and `onCreate` methods to confirm that's the case.

Comment: @Pawel This seemed to be the case. answerRadios was never truly destroyed. That is add to me considering I am not an android developer. Would you be able to explain this behavior a little better?

Comment: I'm sure you can find detailed explanation of fragments lifecycle. But issue you had is fragments can be added to activity without active view representation (detached state) which is a common case when using them in `ViewPager`.